# An alternative concept of a 'derivative'

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The definition of the derivative of a function $f$ at $x$ $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{x+h-x}$$ arises from considering its *gradient*, given by $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. This yields a gradient function from which the gradient at any suitable point $(x, f(x))$  can be calculated.

This process is obviously very useful as the gradient is connected to concepts such as tangents and stationary points, and sometimes represents a useful physical quantity such as acceleration.

However, what if we were interested in finding *normals* to a graph, rather than tangents? Considering the definition of the derivative from first principles, we could introduce an analogous definition for finding a 'normal function' rather than a gradient function; the gradient of the normal is given by $-\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$, so we could define this alternative 'derivative' by $$f\star(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{f(x) -f(x+h)}$$
using $f\star(x)$ to denote this idea.

My question is, has this process been explored, and does it have any applications? Of course, anything that can be accomplished with this can (presumably) be accomplished with the usual derivative and the negative reciprocal relationship $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{f\star(x)}$ so it may well be obselete, but I'm wondering if there is use for it elsewhere.

In particular, the inverse of differentiation (in the standard sense) is definitely useful - integrals have geometrical significance and antiderivatives can also represent useful quantities. If we introduce an analogous 'integration' as the inverse of differentiation - so the process by which $f \star (x)$ becomes $f(x)$ - then what, if any, is the geometrical significance of these 'integrals'?

Experimenting with this definition, I found analogies to the usual chain rule, quotient rule and product rule; for instance if  $f(x) = g(h(x))$, then $$f \star (x) = -\left[ g\star (h(x)) \right] * \left[h\star (x) \right]$$ although the others were more unwieldy. Are there any other properties of differentiating in the usual sense that can be translated into the analogous definitions?

One consequence that is particularly apparent when 'differentiating' trigonometric functions is that the alternative derivative is undefined at stationary points; for instance if $f(x) = \sin x$ then $f \star (x) = -\sec x$ which is undefined at every $\frac \pi 2 + n \pi$ with integer $n$.

I couldn't find any examples of this idea but I wasn't sure what to search for, as clearly this isn't a derivative in the usual sense of the word and 'normal function' is not a very insightful search query - the proper terminology and notation would be very helpful, if it exists.

Comment: Somewhat related are my sci.math posts from [8 October 2005](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/JRN8axz7Zwk/zwPb19kriy4J) and [24 December 2005](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/1SBs0M7GEfI/24BNkPgI9a0J), as well as the Wikipedia page [*Multiplicative Calculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus) (which is relatively new, and which I had not seen until now), and the website [*Non-Newtonian Calculus*](https://sites.google.com/site/nonnewtoniancalculus/) by Michael Grossman and Robert Katz (FYI, I have a copy of their 1972 book).